# Creating a Simple, Free Web Mapping Application

Tags: web-mapping

I have recently left my job as a GIS Specialist that I've held for a number of years. This was my first GIS job and I managed to lean a lot. Now that the holidays are over, I've decided to search for the next position.

Obviously, someone in my position should want to garner a few new skills while I'm on the job hunt. One thing that I didn't have a chance to work with, is web mapping applications in my previous position. It's a skill I'd really like to pick up because it's the present and future of GIS.

My idea is, to start an online resume of sorts. Something I can create and send to prospective employers to show I can work in the GIS environment. Although resumes are great, I feel like this is a lot more tangible than spitting out a bunch of facts about what I do in a resume. When I was hiring people, I had a few people do this sort of thing and I find I have a lot more confidence in people I hire because I can see what they are capable of.

I'm wondering, for all of you who work with web mapping, where should I start? I want to start simple, but have the ability to expand when I get comfortable with it. I'm not willing to fork out money for ESRI products because, well.....I'm unemployed. I want to start working on some open source freeware products. I think Quantum GIS with the OSGEO package seems to be the most popular? I've worked with QGIS in my previous position for desktop and development applications, but I haven't created a web application. What other good, free products are out there that you have used with some success. Is there anything really cool in open source like 3D mapping? I was thinking about creating a 3D fly through tour video using some DEM's or LiDAR if I can get my hands on that sort of data. Any thought, suggestions?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Have you tried searching this site already? There are several questions that directly relate to this topic. If so, what options have you explored already? What would the goal/audience of your first web map be?

Comment: Yes, i kinda of looked around and saw some resources, but I really don't get a sense of what employers are really looking for for web mapping skill sets. Good question about my audience. I'm kinda stuck on this. My background is in oil and gas and forestry so my focus will be resource based. I will be looking for jobs in those fields so I think, whatever free data I can find will point me in the direction of my audience. It's not perfect, but it's what I have to work with.

Comment: 3 recommended readings from this site: 1) [How to make the jump from GIS Technician/Analyst to GIS Web Map Developer/Programmer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/professionally-how-did-you-make-the-jump-from-gis-technician-analyst-to-gis-web), 2) [How to Start Web Mapping?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping), 3) [Alternatives to ArcGIS Online?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55119/alternatives-to-arcgis-online).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into CartoDB. There is a free online class being offered by GeoSpatial Training Services that uses CartoDB for curriculum. I think that would match what you are looking for. (I'm not affiliated with either firm)